# Why can my application see some user's likes and not others?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, facebook, facebook-graph-api

As far as permissions are concerned, I'm asking for `email` only (apart from the basic info).

Now, I can use an **application access token** to query `https://graph.facebook.com/FB-USER-ID/movies` and get the list of movies the user likes, but this only works for some users and not others.

You're supposed to have to ask for the `user_likes` and/or `friends_likes` permission to be able to see this info. Because I can see it for some users, my first guess was they have that information public, and others don't. But I can't find such a setting on Facebook.

Anyone knows what's going on here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The settings are in the gear cog on this page http://www.facebook.com/editprofile.php?sk=activities so you can set who can view what.

What you want to do is ask for your `user_likes` permission so that you can get that access to private profiles too.

Comment: Nice find. However, I changed those for myself and am still able to see my own movies with the app. So, that can't be it.

Comment: Did you delete your user instance and revokes access from Facebook and then try again? It might be cached.

Comment: You're right. I revoked permissions, cleared cookies, went into the app again, and el zilcho. Thanks.